# How do I resolve "JIT Compiler Unavailable" with Angular 13?

Tags: angular, npm, jit, angular-aot

I am working on a server-side routing assignment with Angular v13 and Express. The first page is a login screen that validates an ID and then directs to a home page. When I try to run my application with 'npm run localhost' I cannot get it to load, but when I run 'ng serve' I am able to get the page to load. I get a "JIT Compiler Unavailable" message in the console when I run the 'npm run localhost'.

I have read the documentation online about using a Babel plugin, but I am still lost how to set this up. There is a lot said about configuring the webpack.config file for the Babel pluggin, but I do not see that webpack file in my application. I'm confused why I am able to get the pages loaded with 'ng serve' but not with localhost. I'm trying to test the sign-in page with my MongoDB database.

Any help for a beginner is much appreciated! : )

Comment: Facing same, Any Solution you got for this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these compiler options in tsconfig.json file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "compilationMode": "partial",
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
}
```

Comment: Could you add more context? What does this do and why is it necessary?